# Grant local admin rights for period of time (e.g. 15 minutes)

Tags: windows-7, permissions, administrator

Is there a way in Windows 7 to grant admin rights for a specified period of time (e.g. 15 minutes)? I normally operate as a normal user, but I have a local admin account for installations and other operations that normally require admin rights.

For example, on my machine, admin rights are required even to delete a shortcut from the desktop. If I want to delete, e.g. 5 desktop icons, I need to either have enough foresight to delete all of them at once, or I need to supply the admin password 5 separate times. It would be MUCH easier to grant admin rights for a some period of time during these clean-up operations. I'm assuming there might be something similar to sudo (unix) that only asks for admin password once before a specified time-out period. But I can't find any such info after a google search!